# Looking for an 20+-year-old dark fantasy book series, possibly a series, about a girl being taken by a gargoyle thing

Tags: story-identification, books

I thought the series was by Tannith Lee, but looking over her books, I can't find it. I believe it was a trilogy, and the copy my mom had was from the SF&F Bookclub. It starts out with a girl being sacrificed or captured by some kind of gargoyle, and taken to a place in the middle of the desert. I believe there were several other women already there, and it was a Beauty and the Beast kind of setup at first. The girl ends up freeing the gargoyle of his curse, IIRC, and later goes on to become a very powerful witch of some kind.

It's been about twenty years since I read the series, so I'm a bit light on the specific details. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is the [Dark Angel Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Darkangel_Trilogy). Unfortunately the wiki link seems to be the best link but I think it spoils a little bit of the story. The series is by Meredith Ann Pierce. It takes place on the terraformed moon. A young slave woman allows a vampire prince to capture her so that she can stay with her mistress who he has taken for his bride. She ends up taking care of her and his other 12 brides as their only servant also there are gargoyle creatures (each with a different animal head) that keep her and the brides from escaping. It's definitely a Beauty and the Beast/ Icarus inspired story.

Comment: That's it, thank you. :)